# Explaining why choose from a set without choose consecutive numbers is equal to the number of solutions of a equation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I need to solve this question:

> We want to count the number of ways to choose five elements from the set $\left\{1,2,\dots,20 \right\}$ with the restriction that we may not choose consecutive integers.
>
> $\bullet$ Why is this number equal to the number of positive integer solutions to the equation $$l_1+l_2+l_3+l_4+l_5+l_6 = 21$$ with the additional restriction that $l_2,l_3,l_4,l_5 > 1$?

My solution:

To choose elements from a set without get consecutive numbers, we have a [stars-and-bars problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29). With this, we get the number of ways for choose from the set $\left\{1,2,\dots,20\right\}$.$$\left(\begin{array}{c} n-k+1 \\ k\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c} 16 \\ 5\end{array}\right)$$.

Now, we need to get the number of solutions for the equation.

$l_1,l_6 \subseteq \left\{0,1,\dots,13\right\}$

$l_2,l_3,l_4, l_5 \subseteq \left\{2,3,\dots,15\right\}$

With this, we have the number of solutions: $$\left(\begin{array}{c} 14 \\ 2\end{array}\right) + \left(\begin{array}{c} 13 \\ 4\end{array}\right)$$

Here is where I got stuck. I don't know how to explain why this occurs.

Comment: Note although $l_1,l_6$ can be any of the 14 numbers, it is possible that $l_1 = l_6$, so $14 \choose 2$ is not quite correct, as this always pick distinct values. Further there are some additional constraints. For instance, we cannot have $l_1 = 13, l_6=12$, because the sum $l_1 + \cdots + l_6$ would have exceede 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint to your problem**: Consider the 5 nonconsecutive numbers you picked, and look at the gaps between them (think of the chosen numbers as the "bars" in stars-and-bars). What do you observe about these gaps?

This is a **bijective approach**, namely we will show for each way to pick 5 nonconsecutive numbers from $1,\ldots,20$, we can find a corresponding sum for 21 satisfying the constraints you described.

Indeed, say you picked five nonconsecutive numbers and order them  $a_1 < a_2 < a_3 < a_4 < a_5$ from $\{1,\ldots,20\}$. Then consider the six numbers
$$a_1 ,\quad a_2 - a_1 ,\quad a_3-a_2 ,\quad a_4-a_3 ,\quad a_5 - a_4,\quad 21-a_5.$$ Note their sum is 21, and every number is positive with the middle four strictly greater than 1, as $a_i$'s are nonconsecutive. You will have to convince yourself why if you pick different five nonconsecutive numbers we will get a different set of six in this way.

Conversely, we can reverse this process. If we pick six positive numbers $l_1,\ldots,l_6$ such that $l_1 + \cdots + l_6 = 21$ with $l_2,\ldots,l_4>1$ , then consider five numbers:
$$
l_1,\quad l_1+l_2,\quad l_1+l_2 +l_3,\quad l_1+l_2+l_3+l_4,\quad l_1+l_2+l_3+l_4+l_5
$$
Then you can check indeed these five numbers are nonconsecutive, and all from $\{1,\ldots,20\}$, and that if you pick a different set of $l_i$'s, you will get a different set of five nonconsecutive numbers.

Comment: Thanks @bonsoon, I appreciate that. I didn't understand how the concept between these two are connected. Now I understood better.